# Android Studio class file for com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture not found

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I cannot build my project due to it failing because it cannot find a class. Is there something wrong with my sdk or dependancies?

I have tried invalidating cache and restarting. I am using api 29.

The following is where the error shows up

```
public class PodcastUpdateWorker extends Worker {

}
```

Here is the error printout

```
/home/snowman/AndroidStudioProjects/CorbettReportPodcasts/app/src/main/java/com/example/corbettreportpodcasts/PodcastUpdateWorker.java:36: error: cannot access ListenableFuture
public class PodcastUpdateWorker extends Worker {
       ^
  class file for com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture not found
```

and my dependancies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5"
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: I narrowed it down to issue with the exoplayer imports

Comment: There is an issue with the exoplayer library conflicting with listenablefuture causing it not to be found. [Read Here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7993)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is an issue with the exoplayer library conflicting with listenablefuture causing it not to be found. [READ MORE](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7993)

you can include guava `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android'` to fix this

Comment: Thanks. Tricky thing. I wonder, how to find out resolutions for such problems on one's own...

Comment: @sberezin exactly, it brings down my confidence :D

Comment: Don't be disheartened, I usually check the mailing lists or repository issues for the package in question if I run into a problem. At the time I answered this I had only been learning Android for 2 months.

Answer (score 6):

```
implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent

Comment: Did not work for me. I believe it is project configuration issue but i cant be sure

Answer (score 0):

Check for the package name in gradle scripts (module:app) and in `...app>src>main>java`.

Rename the folder to the desired package name. Make sure that the package name is changed in all the java files also. After renaming, sync your project with gradle files.

If you are doing this after the first Gradle sync, then this trick may not work. You need to change them manually.

Comment: I incorrectly tried to change the project name in the question i asked. Sorry. The question has been updated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" 
to 
api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

also update these to latest versions, if applicable

```
api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2' 
api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32"
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the accepted answer. I didn't user Exoplayer in the application. After digging deeper I found that if you use Google's library for guava to fix conflicts like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

This will also cause an issue. Removing this dependency solved the problem. BUT on the other hand, if you use some library, which causes the problem with `listenablefeature` in opposite adding this dependency solves the problem.